# Is it possible to link up more than one step with relative paths?

Tags: html, hyperlink, relative-path

Here is an example of what I'm looking to do:

Link from a page with the path `http://mysite.com/lorem/ipsum/ to http://mywebsite.com/` using a relative path.

My first thought was to use this: `<a href='.../'>link</a>`. But this ends up giving me `http://mysite/lorem/ipsum/.../`.

Is there a way to do this without calling the actual URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
<a href="../../">link</a>
```

:)